# My C program prints -39 on a new line and I can't figure out why

Tags: c, printf, program-entry-point, stdio

I've been playing around and trying to experiment with C for my university class and I've found something that my program does even though I did not tell it to!

My full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("%d\n", (c - '1'));
  }
 return 0;
}
```

The output of it looks like this:

```
7
6
-39
```

Now, can anyone tell me why that -39 is being printed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty clear if you look at [**this**](http://www.asciitable.com/). First you entered `8` then `7` and then you entered `\n` (or pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) which has ASCII value of `10`. `10-49` (`49` being the ascii value of `'1'`) is `-39` you have printed it.

Answer (score 0):

because you input the 'enter' at the end so it subtract the ascii value of enter with ascii value of 1 .

The ascii value of enter is 10 & ascii of 1 is 49 so 10-49 is equal to 39 .